# postgresql writing a variable to a file or append a select output to a file avoid "copy to"

Tags: postgresql

Regarding postgresql, I need to write to a file the result of a loop that does a number of selects.

The "copy to" does not seem to allow to append to a file and moreover is coubersome because does not allow to set delimiters as empty strings and I am obliged to set delimeters to space and tab.

Any other idea for writing a text variable of pgsql to a file, or for appending during "copy to" to the file.

Another problem is that the file name cannot be a variable of pgsql, is there a solution to that ?

Answer (score 0):

Postgres provides for file writing (below is an excerpt from my code).

```
perform pg_catalog.pg_file_unlink(fn); -- I delete the file
perform pg_catalog.pg_file_write(fn,r,false); -- I accumulated the string to write into r.
```

These functions are available with the [adminpack](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/adminpack.html) that must be installed as e.g. described in [adminpack installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/184577/postgresql-9-1-adminpack-install).

The above functions solve both the problem of writing to a file with the name given by an expression and the problem of writing an expression to the file.

In my case giving only a file name the file gets written in: `/var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main` (I use ubuntu).